# ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550

Tags: php, jquery, imagick

I'm trying to choose an image, which i want to upload to server and to database. HTML code of a button, on which i click to choose an image:

```
<form>
    First image<input type="file" id="input" onchange="AddPicture(this, 'frontImg')" />
    <input type="hidden" name="frontImg" />
</form>
```

AddPicture function code:

```
function AddPicture(what, cover_side){
AIM.start(what,{
    beforeComplete:function(){
        },
    onComplete:function(returnData){
            console.log(returnData);
            var jdata=$.parseJSON(returnData);
            for (var i=0; i<jdata.filename.length; i++){
                $("." + cover_side).html("<img src=\""+http_addr+"img/lobby/"+jdata.filename[i]+"_small.jpg\" />");
                $("input[name="+cover_side+"]").val(jdata.filename[i]);
            }
    },
    UPtarget:http_addr+'plugins/upload/upload.php'}
);
}
```

AIM.js: http://pastie.org/10356501 (honestly speaking, i dont even know why do i need this file)

upload.php: http://pastie.org/10356500

What i already tried:

I entered a console.log(returnData); string in my AddPicture func to see what i get and this is what i get, when i'm trying to choose an image, which i want to upload:

> "
>   **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `../../img/lobby/both.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550' in /.../public_html/plugins/upload/upload.php:48
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /.../public_html/plugins/upload/upload.php(48): Imagick->__construct('../../img/lobby...')
>
> ## 1 {main}
>
> thrown in **/.../public_html/plugins/upload/upload.php** on line **48**
>   "

Server is running on FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p21, Apache 2.0 Handler, imagick module version    3.1.2, ImageMagick 6.8.0-7 2014-01-28 Q16.

What should i do to get rid of this error ? Recently it worked, but now i get this this error, reason why this error appeared i dont know.

Comment: Have you checked that the file is actually a valid jpeg? i.e. just open it in a browser or any picture editor.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, i tried to open it with a picture editor and it normally opened.

Comment: "Recently it worked, but now i get this this error" - you're probably going to  have to find out what changed on your server...